# How to get text from LINQ to SQL query into a TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a web page in which I am giving USER the options of writing notes. Now when ever the web page checks that a USER is:abc then it pulls up the note from the MEMO Table.

Here is my code in Page_Load():

```
using (EntityMemoDataContext em = new EntityMemoDataContext())
{
    int getEntity = Int16.Parse(Session["EntityIdSelected"].ToString());
    var showMemo = from r in em.EntityMemoVs_1s
                   where r.EntityID == getEntity
                   select r.Memo;

    tbShowNote.Text = String.Join(@"<br />", showMemo);
}
```

tbShowNote is showing me value like this in the textbox:

```
test<br />test1<br />test1<br />test4<br />test4
```

And I want it like this:

> Test
>   Test1
>   Test1
>   Test4
>   Test4

Comment: did you htmlencode when u first time saved it in the db

Comment: nops! It is going like a text!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 tbShowNote.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, showMemo);
```

Even better if your textbox is multiline you should be able to assign the lines directly:

```
 tbShowNote.Lines = showMemo.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about "\r\n" instead of 
?  Also, make sure the text box is multiline.